# How can I make SCNNode position animation move at a uniform rate?

Tags: transactions, core-animation, scenekit

I have a game that I am animating in swift using scenekit and the provided animation framework, core animation.

The problem I am having is that my animation is not smooth. Moving a node from point A to point B results in a small ramp up in move speed and a small ramp down when it gets close to the desired position. I wish for the speed to remain uniform throughout. This is a problem because my animations don't move very far and they happen frequently (2 per second + computational delay) resulting in it looking very jerky.

So my question is, is there any way to make the animation speed uniform?

Edit: Just for clarity I am using SCNTransaction. My code looks something like this: Half pseudocode

```
func simulate(){
    SCNTransaction.begin()
     SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)
    SCNTransaction.setCompletionBlock{
        //If no victory this simulate func is run again
        checkVictory()
    }

    for all gameObjects{
    object.position = calculateNewPos()
 }
 SCNTransaction.commit()

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the default timing function is `kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault`.

Setting `SCNTransaction`'s `animationTimingFunction` to `[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]` might solve your issue.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. I only had one problem and that was that instead of setting the timing function to: 

CAMediaTimingFunction(name: "kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear")

I had to set it to:

CAMediaTimingFunction(name: "linear")

Which i find is very odd since that exact string isn't listed on their docs and i found purely by guesswork

Comment: `kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear` is a constant, and must not be quoted: `CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)`